# Keeping the longest value among variables in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I just started programming in r, so I am a little shaky when it comes to some simple tasks. I have a data.frame that has multiple years of data. One variable I have for each year is state. My data.frame looks something like this:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID    State_14   State_15   State_16
 1      Alabama      Alabama     NA
 2      California   NA          NA       
 3      Texas        Texas       Texas", header = TRUE)
```

I want only one variable for state (the elements of that variable would be Alabama, California, Texas). I was thinking of finding the longest element in each row, and having that be the value for my new state variable. How would I do this? Is there a better "r" way to do this?

Comment: Try with `apply` `dat$newstate <- apply(dat[-1], 1, function(x){ x1 <- x[!is.na(x)]; x1[which.max(nchar(x1))]})`

Comment: Is there always only one state per  row?

Comment: The `dplyr::coalesce` function would probably be useful here: `mutate(dat, State=coalesce(State_14, State_15, State_16))`

Comment: Thanks for that coalesce function Mr flick, that does the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

akrun beat me to the `apply` solution...so had to think of another way...

`coalesce` in `dplyr` can accomplish this.  If all of these variables have the same prefix, you can use `starts_with` (Thanks Mr. Flick)

```
library(dplyr)
dat$state <- do.call("coalesce", dat %>% select(starts_with("State_")))
```

Comment: If there are a lot of columns, `do.call("coalesce", dat %>% select(starts_with("State_")))` could help.

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking for this.  was trying to accomplish with `grep` and couldn't make it happen.  Updated above.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!